# Is there a way to launch a popup for mobile device browser ONLY if App not already installed?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ipad

I am looking for a way to launch a popup when a website is viewed via a mobile browser, asking the user if they would like to install our App. But I only want the popup prompt to appear if the App is not already installed.

I have used the following JavaScript (which will work for Apple devices:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( /iPad|iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
var url=confirm("Would you like to download our mobile application?");
if (url==true)
{
var url = window.location.href = 'http://www.itunes.com';
url.show(); 
}
else
{
}
}
</script>
```

As has been discussed here: [App notification popup mobile device web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617748/app-notification-popup-mobile-device-web-browser)

However, this popup launches on iOS regardless. I understand you can check for an app url scheme (and so find out if the App is installed) here: [How to launch apps (facebook/twitter/etc) from mobile browser but fall back to hyperlink if the app isn't installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-you-can-launch-facebook-twitter-apps-from-the-browse)

Can I accomplish this by incorporating these two techniques?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if your app has a custom URL scheme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startMyApp()
{
  document.location = 'appCustomScheme://';
  setTimeout( function()
  {
      if( confirm( 'Install app?'))
      {
        document.location = 'http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yourAppId';
      }
  }, 300);
 }
</script>
```

and call the function `startMyApp()` on page load, or if you need to bind it to some javascript event (click, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to detect whether twitter or Facebook is installed in your device you can use this in your script.

```
var url = window.location.href = 'fb://';
```

for twitter

```
var url = window.location.href = 'twitter://';
```

If it does not work, try taking out the //. The above statements will open the twitter or facebook app, you can use that in a if loop or something to detect whether a app is installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks! Presumably this works for the registered uri:scheme of our app?

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie - could you give an example of how to incorporate this into java? e.g. if iphone/if browser AND if app not installed THEN display popup prompt? Thanks so much